# c# confused with lambda expression in set property

Tags: c#, lambda

I've read some code  in setting property for a class like below

```
private int id;
public int ID {
    get=>id;
    set=>id=value;
}
```

and it works. But I'm totally confused by the lambda syntax.

I know that lambda expression would be `(input-parameters) => expression`.
how could it drop brackets in the left.

I've search the answer in google but not found. the likely answer would be that get&set should be equal to delegate, but I've no idea about this. Does someone has document about this?

Comment: it's a C# 7 feature called 'expression bodied members' - that should give you some good results in google.

Comment: so it is new feature in c# 7?

Answer (score 1):

You could find the usage of lambda of `C#` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)

Quoted here:

> To create a lambda expression, you specify input parameters (if any)
>   on the left side of the lambda operator =>, and you put the expression
>   or statement block on the other side.

Note the **(if any)**

Comment: @Alisson I think the other answer maybe the right one since this need a delgate to work acording to the document

Comment: @KenallChen you should un-accepted this answer and accept andres R's answer, then I can delete this one for preventing of further confusing of other people.

Answer (score 0):

As Furmek mentioned, these are called expression bodied members. These are similar, but different than lambda functions.

Another way of writing this is:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Or you could go the other way ;) private int id; public int ID => id;